# Cursor moving to bottom of page

Tags: system-settings, civicrm.settings

I moved my civiCRM (5.59.3) to a new hosting site. Now, when entering the first name of a new contact the cursor goes to the bottom of the page rather than the next data box.

Is there a way to control cursor behavior somewhere in the settings?